# 10gen mms monitoring service to start after reboot

Tags: linux, mongodb, amazon-web-services, monitoring, pymongo

I have setup MMS agent for my mongoD instances on AWS. MMS Agent is on a separate t1.micro instance. It all works fine however, every time I reboot the server I have to run `sudo nohup python agent.py > agent.log  2>&1 &` to start the service!!

How can I add this to service so with every reboot MMS Agent starts too!

Comment: You can add an upstart script however this may be better for a non-programming site, this is really server admin

Answer (score 0):

need a cronJob in monitoring system, when your system reboot, this auto execute in bash line